# How to return to previous activity when current activity having SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I know how to return to previous activity as usual.The current activity(`VideoActivity.java`) is having the `SurfaceView` for the `MediaRecorder` to record video.  Whenever I implement the `finish()` to return to previous activity, it causing the error like logcat below:

```
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned 
E/EmulatedCamera_Preview: onNextFrameAvailable: Unable to dequeue preview window buffer: 19 -> No such device
```

The logcat just repeat the above 2 line and become very long list,therefore I just show this 2 line.

Besides showing the logcat above,whenever I intent to `VideoActivity.java` the application is stop.

**This is how I implement to return to the previous activity**

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isRecording){
                    stopRecording();
                    finish();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }

        }
    });
```

Basically I implement the SurfaceView like this:

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    surfaceHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isRecording){
                stopRecording();
                finish();
            }else{
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    prepareRecorder();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.release();
    mCamera.release();

    // once the objects have been released they can't be reused
    mRecorder = null;
    mCamera = null;    }

}
```

This code is working fine before I return to previous activity using `finish()`.

So my question is,if an activity having `SurfaceView`,how can it return to previous activity?Please show me the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I didnt release the `Camera` and `MediaRecorder`.I able to solve this by release the `Camera` and `mediaRecorder` before `finish()`,so the code is look like this

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isRecording){
                    Log.d("Video","stop recording");
            try{
                   mRecorder.stop();
            }catch (RuntimeException e) {

            }
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            mCamera.lock();
            isRecording = false;
            releaseCamera();
                    finish();
                }else{
                    releaseCamera();
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
}

private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            surfaceHolder.removeCallback(VideoActivity.this);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            // clear recorder configuration
            mRecorder.reset();

            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;

            mCamera.lock();
        }
}
```